# Exception in Stream.anyMatch

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, stream

I have some code that is playing with the java `stream` api:

```
boolean isAuthorized = authorizationByTenant.stream()
                .filter(auth -> auth.getTenantName().equalsIgnoreCase(tenant))
                .map(auth -> auth.getAuthorizedRoutes().get(component))
                .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                .anyMatch(routeDefinition -> isMatchingRoute(routePath, routeDefinition));
```

And I sometime get an `Exception` pointing to the `anyMatch` line:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: null at
> java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:273)
> ~[na:na] at
> java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
> ~[na:na] at
> java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
> ~[na:na] at
> java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.tryAdvance(ArrayList.java:1602)
> ~[na:na] at
> java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:129)
> ~[na:na] at
> java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:527)
> ~[na:na] at
> java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:513)
> ~[na:na] at
> java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
> ~[na:na] at
> java.base/java.util.stream.MatchOps$MatchOp.evaluateSequential(MatchOps.java:230)
> ~[na:na] at
> java.base/java.util.stream.MatchOps$MatchOp.evaluateSequential(MatchOps.java:196)
> ~[na:na] at
> java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
> ~[na:na] at
> java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.anyMatch(ReferencePipeline.java:632)
> ~[na:na] at
> com.mycompany.routefilter.functionality.FunctionalityService.isAuthorizedRoute(FunctionalityService.java:55)
> ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT] at

My question here is what is `null` ? Is it `routeDefinition` ? And why does it make the call fails ? I expect that if `routeDefinition` is null my method `isMatchingRoute` would return false.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show isMatchingRoute ?

Comment: we have no idea about any of the involved methods or data - how are we expected to know what is `null` - it could be `.get(component)` returning `null` (my favorite), or returning some collection with `null` elements; or `auth.getTenantName()`, `routePath`, `isMatchingRoute`, ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The NullPointerException is occurring in your `.flatMap(Collection::stream)` expression.

I created a similar example and expanded the method reference into a lambda. When causing a null value there you will see the stacktrace become more clear.

Example:

```
Stream.of("foo")
    .map(foo -> (List<String>) null)
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .anyMatch(string -> "gnarly".equals(string)); // LINE 13
```

Leads to

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:271)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$StreamBuilderImpl.tryAdvance(Streams.java:397)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:127)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:488)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
at java.base/java.util.stream.MatchOps$MatchOp.evaluateSequential(MatchOps.java:230)
at java.base/java.util.stream.MatchOps$MatchOp.evaluateSequential(MatchOps.java:196)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.anyMatch(ReferencePipeline.java:528)
at Test.main(Test.java:13)
```

When I replace it with:

```
  Stream.of("foo")
        .map(foo -> (List<String>) null)
        .flatMap(strings -> strings.stream()) // LINE 11
        .anyMatch(string -> "gnarly".equals(string)); // LINE 12
```

Then the exception becomes:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Test.lambda$main$1(Test.java:11)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:271)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$StreamBuilderImpl.tryAdvance(Streams.java:397)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:127)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:488)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.MatchOps$MatchOp.evaluateSequential(MatchOps.java:230)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.MatchOps$MatchOp.evaluateSequential(MatchOps.java:196)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.anyMatch(ReferencePipeline.java:528)
    at Test.main(Test.java:12)
```

Here you see at the top of the stack trace that the real cause is in line 11. A bit confusing indeed, but I guess the JRE cannot report exceptions occurring within method references with line number accuracy.

EDIT: Regarding solutions, my IntelliJ suggests the following:

[image: IntelliJ suggestions]

The filter:

```
.filter(Objects::nonNull)
.flatMap(Collection::stream)
```

The null safe lambda:

```
.flatMap(strings -> strings != null ? strings.stream() : null)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is mainly failing at `.flatMap(Collection::stream)`.

This is mostly because you are not handling null check in `.map(auth -> auth.getAuthorizedRoutes().get(component))`. So to avoid this scenario, you can either do filter before calling flatmap:

```
boolean isAuthorized = authorizationByTenant.stream()
                .filter(auth -> auth.getTenantName().equalsIgnoreCase(tenant))
                .map(auth -> auth.getAuthorizedRoutes().get(component))
                .filter(auth -> auth.getAuthorizedRoutes().get(component)!= null)
                .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                .anyMatch(routeDefinition -> isMatchingRoute(routePath, routeDefinition));
```

The hint which I have found out is based on `java.base/java.util.stream.MatchOps$MatchOp.evaluateSequential(MatchOps.java:230) ~[na:na] at` line of stacktrace.

`MatchOps$MatchOp` is accepting predicate and determines if elements of source stream (in your case stream generated from `flatMap`) matches predicate or not. So this confirms that your flatMap is generating `null` value which in turn takes input of your `map` call.